# jQuery Ajax Request Parsing Invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending an AJAX request with jQuery to the Google Maps API. However, it seems to return incorrectly-formatted JSON (or I get an error as such).

Here is my function call:

```
jQuery.ajax({url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json", 
             data: {mode: "driving", 
                    units: "imperial", 
                    origins: start_point, 
                    destinations: end_point}, 
             async: false, 
             dataType: 'jsonp', 
             crossDomain: true}).responseText
```

I get this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

This is what the response looks like (I replaced most of the actual values for privacy):

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "end_address" ], // this line is highlighted for the error
   "origin_addresses" : [ "start_address" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "some_distance",
                  "value" : some_number
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "some_time",
                  "value" : another_number
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Is there any way to fix this? I thought I could somehow prevent jQuery from checking for errors, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I see jsonp, but it appears the result is just json.

Comment: That error usually occurs when the response is lacking the "Padding" of JSON-P for `dataType: 'jsonp'`. Either the service expects a different parameter than jQuery's default of `callback` or it doesn't support JSON-P.

Comment: I was using JSON-P to allow cross-domain requests.

Comment: @RushyPanchal JSON-P isn't only a client-side solution. The service has to be implemented with support for it. And, it doesn't appear the Distance Matrix API was.